# Blender Driver not rotating

Tags: transforms, drivers

[image]I did a very simple example:

- Created a cube
- Created empty axis
- on Cube > Transform > Rotation > X added driver, chose Empty as the Object and Type as X Location.
  I was hoping that on moving empty axes, the cube would rotate, but it doesn't work.

Comment: From your image it looks as if you've added the driver to the rotation Lock rather than the value as the whole value field should be hilighted in purple, not the padlock icon!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have chosen Y Location, not X and you are driving Lock Rotation X, not Rotation X.

`6.024 + False` is `6.024`,  `bool(6.024)` is `True` so the driver is working and sets object's rotation to locked in X axis.

You should delete the driver from the lock, and add it to the actual property you want to drive:

[image]

Comment: Wow. Thanks I spent a couple of hours and didn't realize the Lock Rotation.